# For generic $f(x)$, can we determine if $f(x^2)$ is even or odd, and how do we interpret the change from $x$ to $x^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is on problem set 1 on MITOCW's 18.01SC course. The solution says that for a generic function f(x), $f((-x)^2) = f(x^2)$ therefore $f(x^2)$ is even.

I believe I may have misunderstood what $f(x^2)$ means.

My line of reasoning is:

Take for example
$$f(x) = 3x^2$$
$$u = x^2$$
$$f(x^2) = f(u) = 3u$$

$f(u)$ is linear in $u$ and has a domain of $[0, + \infty)$. Therefore, if negative $u$ values are not available, can we say the function $f(u)$ is neither odd nor even?

Of course we have examples where the change of variable generates an even function: $$f(x) = x^4, u = x^2 \Rightarrow f(x) = u^2, \text{ which is even.}$$

Comment: If $f(x)=3x^{2}$ then $f(x^{2})=3x^{4}$.

Comment: So I did misunderstand. We are forming a new function g(x) = f(x^2), and concluding that g(x) is even.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot simultaneously have $f(x) = 3x^2$ and $f(u) = 3u$ (unless the domain of $f$ is a subset of $\{0,1\}$), so you're either misunderstanding function notation or you just have a typo.  I assume you meant $f(x^2) = 3x^2$, so that by setting $u = x^2$, we have $f(u) = 3u$.

That's fine, but you're looking at it backwards.  The function $f(u) = 3u$ is the "generic function" which doesn't have to be odd or even or even have a domain on which we can meaningfully talk about odd/even (if we assume $u \in [0,\infty)$)

The function that is necessarily even is the one you started with: $f(x^2) = 3x^2$.  The implied domain for the $x$-values will be symmetric about $0$, so we can always make sense of even/odd symmetry unless the domain of $f$ is trivial (e.g. $\{0\}$)

Comment: Here is an interpretation of my erroneous reading of the original problem set problem; my reading is still correct I believe though. Let g(x) = x^2, h(x) = x. Then f(x) = = 3h(x)^2 = 3g(x) = 3x^2. f takes a linear function h, raises it to a power, and multiplies it by three. f also takes g(x) and multiplies it by three. So changing f(x) to f(g) is  now giving us the relationship between the parabola x^2 and the parabola 3x^2, which is that the latter is a multiple of the former. The change from f(x) to f(g) gives a new function, with a restricted domain. This new function is not odd or even.

Comment: @evianpring In your situation, $f(x) = 3x^2$ and $f(g(x)) = 3x^4$.  No matter how you interpret it, it's false that $f(g) = 3g$ [except in uninteresting cases of _very_ restricted domains].  I wonder if you are having trouble with function notation?

Comment: What _is_ true is that there is some function you've described $T(x) = 3x$ such that $T(g(x)) = f(x)$.  We don't claim that $T$ is even (it's not).  We instead claim $f$ is even (Note that this assumes we define $g$ with as large a domain as possible, which might be another point of trouble... I really don't know where precisely your issue is)

Answer (score 0):

For a general function f(x), if $f(-x)=f(x)$, then it’s an even function. Not sure why your solution says otherwise. In fact, $f((-x)^2)=f(x^2)$ is always true if $x^2$ is in the domain of the function .

In your example, $f(x)=3x^2$ is equivalent to $f(u)=3u^2$. Using a different variable name does not change the function itself, f(u) is still an even function, you have $f(-u)=f(u)$.  If $u=x^2$, you replace u with $x^2, f(x^2)=3x^4$.

Hope this clarifies some confusion.

Comment: Please see comment on @Brian Moehring 's answer to clear up what I was trying to accomplish in changing variables to u.